# How do I adjust transparency of background windows?

Tags: unity, window-manager, transparency

When I switch away from windows (with alt-tab), they seem to turn semi-transparent. When I have a number of windows stacked (but not taking up the full screen), some of the ones behind the (opaque) front one show through others.

Is there a way to adjust the amount of transparency of these non-active windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out (he answered himself) that this functionality can be adjusted with CompizConfig Settings Manager.

(To install CompizConfig, enter `sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager` from a terminal. It's also, as of this writing, available through the Ubuntu Software Centre.)

To adjust the transparency of non-active windows (note these instructions have only been tested on version 14.04):

1. Start CompizConfig.
2. Go to the Effects menu (either click on Effects in the left pane or click All and scroll to the Effects section)
3. Click TrailFocus. Its description is "Adjust the opacity, saturation and brightness of windows based on when they last had focus."
4. Here you can choose either

   1. The Behaviour tab, to configure

      - which window types (e.g. toolbar, utility, dialog, normal) that TrailFocus will affect
      - the number of windows that TrailFocus will track (beyond which number it will consider a window "completly (sic) unfocused")
      - which window in the switcher stack to start fading
   2. The Appearance tab, to configure the opacity, brightness and saturation levels of both focused and unfocused windows